# Yet Another Bad Audit – It was wrong to agree with a moderator

Tags: bug, review-audits

I just got this question – [Conversion from WebM to MP4 in Ubuntu is slow and bad quality](https://superuser.com/q/873941/150988) –
in the [Reopen Review Queue](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/342253). 
The question displays a command and its CLI output,
and makes an attempt to diagnose part of the problem:

> It also does not play with Windows Media Player. 
>   (The reason for this is the mpegv1 to which the file is converted.)

And, most importantly, ***it was not closed!*** 
I opened the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/873941/revisions)
and saw that [slhck♦](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) had closed the question, edited it,
reopened it, and answered it, all within a 23 hour period on Feb 5 / Feb 6. 
(The OP also made substantial edits during this period.)

Since the review queue was asking whether I wanted to reopen a question ***that was already open***
because ***it had been reopened by a moderator***, I concluded that it was an audit
(although, clearly, a poorly constructed one), and so I voted to reopen it. 
Naturally, the audit orc jumped out and hit me with his cudgel:

[image: Stop! Look and Listen. This was an audit. You didn't pass. This question has serious problems that must be fixed before it can be answered.]
                                                             
[<sub>(This image links to a full-sized copy of itself.)</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q18ZS.png)

I guess I have two main points:

- All non-audit entries in the Reopen Queue are closed. 
  So audits in the Reopen Queue should display (in the Review Queue) as being closed. 
  A question that displays as being open is *too* obviously an audit;
  even a robo-reviewer could learn to recognize that. 
  (Presumably any reviewer who follows the link to look directly at the question
  should see its true status.)
- If an RQ audit shows a question that is really open
  (whether it’s one that has never been closed,
  or one that that’s been closed, improved, and reopened),
  the “correct” action (the one that lets you pass the audit) should be reopen. 
  The audits should not require the reviewer to vote to close (or leave closed) questions
  that five users (or one über-user) have chosen to reopen.

P.S. Why does it say
“If you’re unable to fix these problems by Editing, you should Close such questions.”
in the Reopen Queue? 
It should say “…, you should leave such questions Closed.”
or “…, you should vote `Leave Closed` on such questions.” 
And why is it still saying “Stop!  Look ***and Listen***.” when there’s no audio?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that it was closed/reopened by a mod. review audit is just mean like that.

Comment: After reading your question twice I think I understand what you're getting at. The review queue audits should not make you vote to close questions that were already reopened because they've been improved. Is that it?

Comment: I guess I have two main points, in addition to the somewhat cosmetic nit-picks in the “P.S.”

Comment: You should bump this

Comment: I appreciate your support, but I don’t see much point.  Defective review audits are like bad weather; everybody complains about them, but nobody does anything about them.  Putting it another way, the set of people who can possibly do anything about them and the set of people who care seem to have a null intersection.  Besides, I haven’t seen this problem again since then, and I’ve done over 500 Super User Reopen reviews in that time.  Maybe they actually fixed something and just didn’t bother to give me a [status-completed] tag.

Comment: (Although I believe audit failures still demand that you ***listen*** to them!    :-)    )

Comment: P.S.⁠ Nice cat.